# How are these words written in traditional Vulcan calligraphy?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, translation

How the words adun'a (wife) & adun (husband) or Telik (married) written in traditional Vulcan calligraphy? We want to get tattoos of them  but I cannot find anything to help me other than straight letter substitution which would be wrong. We want these done before the cruise for our vow renewal.